# Added Small promo tile but it's not appearing on the store even that it has passed review

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Added Small promo tile but it's not appearing on the store even that it has passed review, any idea what I am missing...
Screenshots
[image: The images inside the console]
[image: Not appearing on the store.]

Comment: OBender Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes posted resolutions below.

Answer (score 1):

It came taht google have a review process for those images also,
I had written to their support and after 2 weeks the icons appeared.